# OpenShift Remote MySQL Access from another machine without port-forward

Tags: mysql, openshift

I have had a good look around but I have yet to find anything concrete on how to remotely access openshift mysql without the use of port-foward.

I have another server with some software running that I would like to have access to the openshift MySQL.

Could someone perhaps direct me on how I would be able to do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose MySQL cartridge as a REST service and then use it with your application. There are many alternatives like https://github.com/alixaxel/ArrestDB , http://phprestsql.sourceforge.net/download.html that you can use.